# Equivalent Swift NSURLSession or Alamofire Curl post

Tags: swift, authentication, curl, alamofire, nsurlsession

I have this curl post that works fine, but for the life of me I can't get it to work with either NSURLSession or Alamofire. The curl that returns fine is:

```
curl https://api.truevault.com/v1/vaults/XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX/blobs \
-X POST \
-u yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyy: \
--form "file=@foo.pdf" \
-H "Content-Type:multipart/form-data"
```

No matter what variation of curl or NSURLSession I do I get a 401 error, but it completes successful with curl! Please help! Thanks!

**CURRENT ALAMOFIRE ATTEMPT**

```
        let headers = ["Authorization": Config.trueVaultKey, "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"]

        Alamofire.upload(
        Alamofire.Method.POST,
        url!,
        headers: headers,
        multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(
                data: dat!,
                name: "file",
                fileName: "license.png",
                mimeType: "image/png"
            )
        },
        encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {

            case .Success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseString { response in
                    //JSON = response.result.value! as String
                    debugPrint(response)

                    print("\n\n\nREQUEST HEADER: \(response.request!.allHTTPHeaderFields!)")
                    print("\n\n\nREQUEST BODY: \(response.request!.HTTPBody)")
                    print("\n\n\nREQUEST BODY STREAM: \(response.request!.HTTPBodyStream)")
                }
            case .Failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
            }
    })
```

Comment: can you post your swift code?

Comment: updated with swift code

Comment: I think you don't need to set headers, multi-part will be added automatically. not sure what is Authorization, but I can't see it in your cURL. is it the XXXX-XXXX-XXXX ? so it should appear in the URL not header.

Answer (score 0):

try to build your URL like this :

```
 let userAuth = "username:password" // credential
 let url = "https://\(userAuth)@api.truevault.com/v1/vaults/XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX/blobs" // notice the at(@) sign
```

do not set the headers, they will be set automatically.

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't work either... still getting 401

Comment: can you update your code with the URL you're calling ? and if any credential let them appear as "username", "password. Having xxxx and yyyy is hard to read.